# Use Kafka Streams with Avro Schema Registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I'm seeking kafka-stream usage with schema-registry. I have google and could't find proper tutorial.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Damitha - Questions about books / tools etc will be taken out from stackoverflow. I think you can ask those in some  forums.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation is here
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#avro

This is the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
    <version>${confluent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you add the repository

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Lots of example code in here. Not all of it uses Avro
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/tree/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams