# My Kafka streaming application just exit with code 0 doing nothing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, slf4j

In order to try the Kafka stream I did this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();

        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "generic-avro-integration-test");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Utils.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, Utils.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
        
        builder.stream(Utils.ALL_FX_EVENTS_TOPIC).foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key));
        
        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }
```

But when I run it locally I only get this :

[image]

Basically I run it from my IDE and after 1 sec it just stops while it should be waiting for new events pushed in the topic.

I don't understand.

The kafka topic is on another machine, but I coded a very simple consumer as well and I was able to read the messages from this remote topic.

For some reason this very simple kafka stream app exit with the code 0.
There is not much I can do, any idea ?

Since the issue seems to be related to the slf4j dependencies here the pom :

4.0.0
    jar

```
<name>Ingestor :: Bigdata :: Ingestor</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent-pom</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>ingestor</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    
    <sq.artifact.type>internal</sq.artifact.type>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
    <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <sq.scs>fx-dan</sq.scs>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>libs-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-schema-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Update :

Beside the missing log4j properties file the error was due a miss configuration for the Serdes.

The updated code looks like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "generic-avro-integration-test");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Utils.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
        streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, Utils.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);

        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final Serde<AllTypesFxEvents> specificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();

        final boolean isKeySerde = false;
        specificAvroSerde.configure(Collections.singletonMap(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, Utils.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL),
                isKeySerde);

builder.stream(Utils.ALL_FX_EVENTS_TOPIC).foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key));

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
```

I don't have the exception stack anymore but this link helped me to fix it.

> [proper guide for java kafka stream with avro schema registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523420/proper-guide-for-java-kafka-stream-with-avro-schema-registry)

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the lines that say something failed. You forgot to add logging libraries, that's why it's printing "nothing"

Comment: Yes I ran it on another machine and I have this NoSuchMethodError: 'org.slf4j.helpers.FormattingTuple org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])'

Comment: Well, did you add Slf4j as a dependency?

Comment: I have now on my local machine it's still the same warning but on the remote I have this one SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
 yet I set the 1.5.6 in my pom

Comment: Can you please add the pom to the question? You should be really be using slf4j-api 1.7.32, I think is the latest. I've personally never ran into any version mismatch error, however. You'll also want to add logback-classic dependency

Comment: I added the pom.xml.

Comment: I was missing the log4j.properties file.... Now I have a huge stack trace...

Comment: So, you've fixed the problem, now, or you have some huge stacktrace/error?

Comment: It's fixed, I updated my main message.

Comment: Please post the solution below the comments section as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issues and here is a summary.

The first issue was that I didn't set up slf4j properly. Kafka expect to have slf4j available because this is what it uses to print the error it encounters. Not having it was silently failing my program.

To resolve this you need to add a log4j.properties file in your resources folder (in your src folder).

Mine looked like this (it doesn't print DEBUG logs):

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Once I had the logs, I had a stack trace about serialization error. I don't have the logs anymore but the other SO post that made me fix it is :

[Use Kafka Streams with Avro Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523420/proper-guide-for-java-kafka-stream-with-avro-schema-registry)

Basically I was using the wrong object for the Serde configuration.

The updated code looks like this :

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "generic-avro-integration-test");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Utils.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
    streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, Utils.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);

    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
    final Serde<AllTypesFxEvents> specificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();

    final boolean isKeySerde = false;
    specificAvroSerde.configure(Collections.singletonMap(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, Utils.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL),
            isKeySerde);

builder.stream(Utils.ALL_FX_EVENTS_TOPIC).foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key));

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me(even with wrong values-at least doesn't terminate). Please use logback in your code and keep logger level to DEBUG. This way you will be able to observe carefully what is happening when your kafka streams is launching.
Probably kafka thread is terminating due to some reason which we can't just guess like that.

PS: Sorry I don't have reputation to add a comment.

Comment: I run the code on the remote machine and for some reason I have a stack trace. It tells me that NoSuchMethodError: 'org.slf4j.helpers.FormattingTuple org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])'

Comment: I guess your remote machine is indicating a different issue related to  SLF4J API's jar version (similar issue is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479811/nosuchmethoderror-with-slf4j-api/11137079) here.